# qt ./configure on Debian

Tags: c++, linux, qt4

I have a debian installation with qt4-dev-tools installed from apt-get.

I want to configure qt for compiling statical applications, but there is no ./configure file - i found the qt directory at /usr/share/qt4, but there is no configure.

Is there another option for configuring it or is the configure file hidden somewhere?

Comment: You have to configure your project, not the system (dev) libraries

Comment: The windows version needs to be configured on the system level also?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: configure qt globally for all projects to configure as static (./configure -static -release -no-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper build environment to configure the way your programs are built. See [qmake](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qmake-manual.html) or [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/documentation.html) documentation for more information. You can also use QtCreator as IDE